# How to get function's cell (not current and not active cell) with Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

With google apps script:

```
  function myFormula() {
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
          // var currentCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell();
          // var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell();
           // this what I would want:
           var theCellWhereFunctionIs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCellWhereFormualIs(); // this what I would want..

    }
```

Q: How to get function's cell (not current and not active cell) with Google Apps script

the theCellWhereFunctionIs

So if I place "=myFunction()" to A1 so myFunction would know that it's A1, getting the cell object of it.

--

If it's not possible. I know I can pass the range to myFunction, like this =myFunction("A1"), where "A1" is current cell/range where that function is.

But then problem is that that "A1" is hard-coded. I wonder what I can do about it? I ve checked on some answers in SE, but couldn't find cleat on.

I can't do this myFunction(A1) because it pass value,  not reference to range/cell object.  There is something about &A1?

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getFormula()`

Comment: You can't.......

Comment: Added more to my question "if it's not possible.." part

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
function getCell(formula) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  formula = sheet.getRange(formula).getFormula();
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    if(formulas[i].indexOf(formula) > -1){
      return sheet.getRange(i+1,formulas[i].indexOf(formula)+1).getA1Notation();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Sample Formula:

- A1  => `=sequence(5)`
- B1  => `=query(A1:A5, "where A > 3")`
- A10 => `=query(A1:A5, "where A > 3")`

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Behaviour:

- It gets the whole range of the sheet via [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- Fetches all formulas within the range
- Loops into each cell and then check if the formula where the parameter points out is present.
- In case of multiple expected results, this will only return the first cell encountered.

#### Sheets:

- In Sheets, `address` is a function that can be used to return what the A1 notation of the cell is. This might be helpful to you.

#### Output:

[image: address]

If I misunderstood what you meant, I sincerely apologize. It would be nice if you could also provide an illustration how it would behave like shown above and how the output would be used so we will not misunderstood your goal and intentions.